# Is it okay to submit an update that is almost different from the first release? This is an iOS app for the Apple App Store

Tags: iphone, ios

I wanna know if it is okay to submit an update to an app that is different from the first release. For example, my first release would be a game, but on my next release, I want to remove the game but instead make a couple of web views and table views, etc. Will Apple stop me from updating the app?

The Mailbox is one example. When I first downloaded it, it doesn't really do anything but countdown on the number of people getting the app. Honestly, I lost patience and didn't bother trying it out. But I don't think it's an entirely different app, just that the countdown was a layer on top of a fully functioning Mailbox app, correct?

Comment: Yes, you can change anything in the updation & submit the new version.

Comment: That being said, replacing your app with a completely different one in an update is a fast path to a lot of negative reviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you update new version, apple review team will review your new ipa, so what have updated write in new version.

So if your new updated app is valid means follow all guidelines than there is no problem.